# 1045 error when using LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to use PHPmyadmin to import a CSV file to a mysql database, however I get a 1045 error. I get the following error:

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'tipsandb_saadat'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: That's a fairly clear error message, isn't it?

Comment: I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a rather old question but I had the same issue with mySql 5.1.61.

What I tried to do was, from a MySql client, to run the following command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/myProjectDir/theFile.csv'
INTO TABLE someTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I gathered information from various places, tried several options and figured out that all these points must be checked:

- the user must have [FILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) privilege:

  GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'theUser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'thePassword';
- the file permissions must be set so that the world can read it (actually it shall be OK if the mysqld process is able to read it):

  chmod o+r theFile.csv
- the file must be located in the [dedicated temporary directory](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/temporary-files.html) that is defined in the my.cnf config file:

  [mysqld]

  tmpdir=/tmp/mysql
- every item in the file path must have its permissions set in the same fashion as the file itself

Answer (score 0):

You need the FILE privilege to use this command.

Comment: I have privilege. is it different with FILE privilege?

Comment: Do you have the "FILE" MySQL privilege?

Comment: I know I have just super privilege access. how I can see that I have FILE MySQL privilege or no ?

Comment: Depending on the phpMyadmin version, click on Privileges or Users then have a look at the 'tipsandb_saadat'@'localhost' account.